# Custom directive models do not work in ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use AngularJS to provide a toggable dropdown list, where the selection of various options will trigger different lists. `ng-switch` seemed like the right way to do it, but my `ng-model` is not binding while inside the `ng-switch`. The binding works fine if I do not use `ng-switch`, but I do not know how to toggle my dropdown lists if that's the case. What could be the issue here?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tanweihao88/LUzXT/3/

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="periodRangeModel" ng-options="item for item in items"></select>
<div ng-switch on="periodRangeModel">
    <span ng-switch-when="Month"><period-selector items="monthOptions" ng-model="periodModel"></period-selector></span>
    <span ng-switch-when="Quarter"><period-selector items="quarterOptions" ng-model="periodModel"></period-selector></span>
    <br>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['Month', 'Quarter'];
    $scope.periodRangeModel = "Month";
    $scope.quarterOptions = ["Jan-Mar", "Apr-Jun", "Jul-Sept", "Oct-Dec"];
    $scope.monthOptions = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    $scope.periodModel = $scope.monthOptions[0];
})
.directive('periodSelector', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { items: '=', ngModel: '='},
        template: "<span><select ng-options='period for period in items' ng-model='ngModel'></select></span>"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason the binding does not work as intended is `ng-switch` creates a new scope and when binding to a string primitive the original `periodModel` isn't being updated as you expect (since the new scope's `periodModel` is being updated).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) has a lot more detail on what's going on behind the scenes and you can check out the [Angular Batarang Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to visually see the various scopes at play.

You can get around it by binding to an object value like in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUzXT/4/). The main changes are:

1) Change `periodModel` to an object and set a property (in this example it's called `value`)

```
$scope.periodModel = {
    value: $scope.monthOptions[0]
};
```

2) Change any binding code to access `periodModel.value` instead of `periodModel`

```
<period-selector items="monthOptions" ng-model="periodModel.value"></period-selector>

Model: {{periodModel.value}} (this is supposed to change)
```

Comment: I see! Thank you! Do you know if there is any way I can recompile the `template`? I have some custom template code that doesn't compile once I toggle to another dropdown list.

Comment: You can recompile html with a different angular html template (see [these docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile)) but it might be overkill for what you're trying to do. Take a look at a [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/LUzXT/5/) of your original example without creating directives in case you can bypass custom directives. If you create a fiddle example I (or someone else) can try and help.

Comment: I was unable to create a fiddle as I'm using third party libraries. In essence, I'm using [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) which uses both css and js to style the dropdown list. But once I toggle the list, the styling is gone.

Comment: I would trying calling the [render()](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#render) method on your select element after the dropdown contents are updated by angular on toggle. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304291/angularjs-how-to-run-additional-code-after-angularjs-has-rendered-a-template) may help with figuring out when to call `render` though I'd test it manually (like in an ng-click event or in the console) first to make sure render is working for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't seem to work, but anyway I got around it by re-initializing the javascript. Thanks!