# ngSwitch slider directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a slider directive inpired by [this example](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-switch/slider-css3-transition-animation) using ngSwitch and ngAnimate but without success. There is a timeout calling the `next` function that increments the `scope.current` variable and ngSwitch should use this variable to switch images.

```
<div class="slider">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RdaZUQscPxL0PiDD60ie) with the example. I think it is something related with the scope(its always you scope).
**UPDATE:** I did some progress, I moved the attributes manipulation to the compile function and it seems it helped a bit but now I get an error: `No controller: ngSwitch`.
[new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RdaZUQscPxL0PiDD60ie)

Comment: You are adding directives in linking function. I think that is wrong because directives are compiled in 'compile' stage and returned linking function is called then. So adding more directives in the element in the linking function won't help.

Comment: Also you will have to add css for actual effect because ng-animate just add classes to elements

Comment: yes I know about the css, that will come later. Should I add the directive in the compile function? I'll test later.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Angularjs shows the error `No controller: ngSwitch` is because `ng-switch-when` depends on `ng-switch`. So you should add the attribute of `ng-switch-when` when the `ng-switch` scope is created. The easiest way is to use `$observe` on the `ngSwitch`.

Here is one way to make the compile work

```
  attrs.$observe('ngSwitch', function () {
      for (i = _i = 0, _len = pages.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
          page = pages[i];
          page.setAttribute('ng-switch-when', i);
      }
  });
```

However the animation will not work since you can't access the `current` value due to the new scope `ng-switch` created.

In order to make the directive work, I think the easiest way is to declare the `ng-switch="current"` in the template so the directive can access to the the value it watches on.

Hope it can shed some light on.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround using ng-if instead of ng-switch, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XfHCnv9TJ9r2R6m95232).

If you want to stick around using ng-switch, I would suggest you give a closer look to the scope created by ng-switch ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909158/custom-directive-models-do-not-work-in-ng-switch)).