# Angularjs - Digest Loop/Repaint timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

having a small issue with AngularJS.  See the following:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'some/url/withJSON.json'})
      .success(function(data) 
               {
               $scope.data = data
               $animations._load('arg1')
               })
```

$animations is a registered service that does some stuff.  Occasionally (maybe 20%) of the time the _load() method will run before the window has been painted/the digest loop completes, meaning the visualisation hasn't completed.  By wrapping _load() with a setTimeout() of 10ms this has resolved it, but is there an implicit/explicit way in AngularJS to execute a callback once the digest loop has finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more information, I would suggest [`$timeout(fn)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) will be the best way to do this. It basically makes sure there's a break after angular completes processing for the browser to render. Roughly it is equivalent to `setTimeout(fn, 0)`, so is what you have already suggested, but it is mockable for testing.

There is also [`$scope.$evalAsync(fn)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) that would normally render after the current digest cycle but before the DOM renders. I tend to prefer `$evalAsync` as it makes things easier for me to reason about, and won't allow other non-angular happenings to occur in the meantime, but it depends which works for you.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225106/anyway-to-trigger-a-method-when-angular-is-done-adding-scope-updates-to-the-dom/17239084#17239084) has more detailed information about the two methods.

Comment: Thanks for this, turns out this is a fairly common bump that needs to be accounted for.  Marking as correct due to links and alternative suggestions provided.