# Understanding Angular data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

While reading about Angular data-binding - came across advice -

> "Due to the nature of JavaScript itself and how it passes by value vs.
>   reference, it’s considered a best-practice in Angular to bind
>   references in the views by an attribute on an object, rather than the
>   raw object itself."

source: ng-book

Question:
1. What does it mean - binding references rather than objects?

This is accompanied by code snippet.

JS Code:

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);
//controller uses $timeout
module.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var updateClock = function () {
        $scope.clock = {};
        $scope.clock.now = new Date();
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.clock.now = new Date();
            updateClock();
        }, 1000);
    };
    updateClock();
})
```

HTML:

```
<body data-ng-app="app">
<div data-ng-controller="MyController">
    <h5>Hello {{clock.now}}</h5>
</div>
</body>
```

Question:
2. If I remove this line `$scope.clock.now = new Date();` from outside the `$timeout` - it does not work. Although `clock.now` is being assigned date object in `$timeout`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

- it has some stuff to do with readability and `this` and scope context
- `{{this.now}}` vs `{{clock.now}}`
- the data binding on the scope might not trigger a digest cycle
- but even then using $scope doesn't resolve debugging issues, and readability entirely

Q2:

- Probably because it needs to re-render, or hasn't run through the digest cycle yet
- [Anyway to trigger a method when Angular is done adding scope updates to the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225106/anyway-to-trigger-a-method-when-angular-is-done-adding-scope-updates-to-the-dom/17239084#17239084)
- [Angular $scope.$apply vs $timeout as a safe $apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070822/angular-scope-apply-vs-timeout-as-a-safe-apply)
- [AngularJS : $evalAsync vs $timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301572/angularjs-evalasync-vs-timeout)
- [How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/how-to-use-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)

Here are three examples, I prefer the syntax of `Controller1` it makes debugging easier imo:

```js
var module = angular.module("app", []);
module.controller("Controller1", function ($timeout) {
        var vm = this
        vm.clock = {now: 'its loading'};
        vm.now = new Date();
        var updateClock = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                vm.clock.now = new Date();
                updateClock();
            }, 3000);
        };
        updateClock();
    })

module.controller("Controller2", function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.clock = {now: 'its loading'};
        $scope.now = new Date();
        var updateClock = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.clock.now = new Date();
                updateClock();
            }, 3000);
        };
        updateClock();
    })

module.controller("Controller3", function ($timeout) {
        var vm = this
        var updateClock = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                try {
                  vm.clock.now = new Date();
                } catch(e){
                  vm.clock = {}
                  vm.clock.now = 'oops'
                }
                updateClock();
            }, 3000);
        };
        updateClock();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body data-ng-app="app">
<div data-ng-controller="Controller1 as vm">
    <h6>vm.clock.now {{vm.clock.now}} vm.now {{vm.now}}</h6>
    <h6>vm: {{vm}}</h6>
</div>

<div data-ng-controller="Controller2">
    <h6>$scope.clock.now {{clock.now}} $scope.now {{this.now}}</h6>
    <h6>this is confusing {{this}}</h6>
</div>  
<div data-ng-controller="Controller3 as vm">
    <h1>{{vm.clock.now}}</h1>
    <h6>nice scope: {{vm}}</h6>
</div>

</body>
```

Also see:

- [What's the difference between ng-model and ng-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419619/whats-the-difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-bind)
- [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Comment: your answer for (2) is very ambiguous.
Sure it has to do with the digest cycle, but what in using $timeout 
or setInterval with angular in general have to do with triggering a digest cycle ?

Comment: @eranotzap i've added links to more explanation on what $timeout and setInterval have to do with a digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

As for question 2: basically if you remove the $scope.clock.now = new Date(); instruction from outside the $timeout callback, in between two digest cycle triggered by the $timeout service, $scope.clock is actually

- assigned to the empty object
- then attached the now property
- then assigned to the empty object again

So the $scope.clock.now variable is always undefined at digest time.

Detailed execution steps from Updateclock function execution start until digest cycle triggered by $timeout service :

- $scope.clock is assigned the empty object
- a timer is set
- the Updateclock function completes
- the timer expires, we enter the timeout callback function where:

  - $scope.clock.now is assigned new Date();
  - updateClock() is called recursively

    - $scope.clock is assigned the empty object again
    - a new timer is set
    - updateClock completes
  - the callback function completes
- at this point the $timeout service triggers a digest
- $scope.clock.now is undefined - like it was before it all begun, and like it will be at the next digest cycle