# How to scroll div height to the bottom in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, scroll

I've been searching a lot for this question and I found some answers but none of them were compatible for my situation.

I am working on `Chat Application` and one of its functionalities is to show older `messages` for some `chat channel`. The element which holds the `messages` is `<table>` and it is set in `<div>` ,and I've set a fixed height and width for this `div`.

I bring channel's messages from `SQL table` by calling the appropriate `servlet`,and show them in the `table` using `AngularJS` .In this situation:is there a way in `html`/`css`/`angular`/`javascript` to scroll the `div` automatically after finishing to upload all the messages?

my code is like that:

`HTML`:

```
<div ng-show="channelmsg">
    <div  style="max-width: 500px; max-length: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;" id="mydiv">
       <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in ChannelMsgResult">
                <td style="border: 1px; border-color =light gray; max-width:400px;">
                    <span><img ng-src={{c.Photo}} style="border-radius:0.5cm; width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
                        <a href="#" style="color: gray;"> {{ c.Nickname }} :</a> </span>
                        <br /> {{ c.Content }} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#"><small>reply</small></a>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#">see replies</a> <br />
                        <label style="color: #9fa1a3;"><small>{{ c.DateTime }}</small></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `Controller's function` that calls the `servlet` and shows (by `ng-show`) the div "mydiv":

```
$scope.displayChannelMsg = function(x) {
     $http.get("http://localhost:8080/ExampleServletv3/displaychannelmsgservlet",{
            params:{
                channelid : x.ChanID
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              $scope.$apply(function(){
                console.log("went to servlet and succeeded")
                $scope.ChannelMsgResult = response;//this variable will hold the channels 
                $rootScope.channelmsg=true;

              });
            });
        });
};
```

Can I do this in a simple way **without using any external libraries (like angular-glue)**?

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an id to each message and then use `$anchorScroll("latest message id");` to scroll to the message

Comment: I added settimeout function and it worked:                                     setTimeout(function () {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
        $anchorScroll('below');
    });     thank you
});

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}, 0);
```

after your first timeout function?

Comment: Well, you need to run it after it fills your table. You could make it a function, but you'd still need to run it after fill.

Comment: can you check: it deals with $scope.$apply:      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225106/anyway-to-trigger-a-method-when-angular-is-done-adding-scope-updates-to-the-dom

Comment: yes exactly ,but this is the problem ,how can I call this function from the html code without clicking any button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136273/discussion-between-darthzejdr-and-shery).