# customSelect() select box not resetting with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm having some problems using the [customSelect()](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/) jquery plugin with Angular.  I'd like to reset my form, but unfortunately, while the angular stuff works, the custom select doesn't reflect the change to the select box.

To see this in action:

- Navigate here:
  http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/f6c2ebecc1843d26e763219a8a69745e
- Change the drop down select filter
- Click the button at the bottom

You'll see all the results show up again, but the select box still has the same value : (

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your DropDown to a Directive!
Check this thread, there is everything you need to get the done: [AngularJS: How to run additional code after AngularJS has rendered a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304291/angularjs-how-to-run-additional-code-after-angularjs-has-rendered-a-template/13619324#13619324)