# Using an Angular directive to inject a JQueryMobile listview template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

Briefly - How to inject markup for JQuery Mobile widgets by way of a directive and have the markup actually convert into a JQM widget.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3AZV93mktxPAPwU4JKgM?p=preview

Given a templateURL within an angular directive, whose target content specifies JQuery Mobile listview markup, how do I ensure that the markup is correctly acted upon by JQuery Mobile so that I get a proper JQM listview widget instead of just styled HTML?

My current attempt is to target the listview within the linking function and call...

```
$("[data-role='listview']",element).listview();
```

This does seem to have an effect in that if I  call this function my unordered list is is then decorated with JQM css classes, but the unordered list is not widgetized as expected by the listview function.

**My Directive**

```
app.directive('testDirective', function () {

    var link=function(scope, element, attrs){
      console.log($("[data-role='listview']"));
      $("[data-role='listview']",element).listview();
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl : "templates/static.html",
        link: link
    };
});
```

**Template Markup JQM-listivew**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data"><a href="#">{{item}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**What the result should look like...**

[image]

**What the result actually looks like**

[image]

**Final Working Directive...**

```
app.directive('testDirective', function () {

  var link=function(scope, element, attrs){
    console.log(element.context.innerHTML);
    var lview=$("[data-role='listview']",element);
    lview.listview();

    scope.$watchCollection("data",function(){
      console.log("watching collection");
      lview.listview("refresh");
    }); 
 };

 return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope:false,
    templateUrl : "templates/static.html",
    link: link
 };
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `.listview();` after angular has finished rendering.

see this for another example:

[AngularJS: How to run additional code after AngularJS has rendered a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304291/angularjs-how-to-run-additional-code-after-angularjs-has-rendered-a-template)

Comment: Is that now what my .listview() call in the linking function is doing?

Comment: Left the listview call within the linking function and added a watch function on data which calls .listview('refresh')

Comment: Updated with one more change, needed to use use scope.$watchCollection  instead of scope.$watch in order to respond to changes in the data after the initial linking.