# OnModelChange after view is rendered

Tags: angularjs

I have a Model that is periodically changed. Every time it is changed and view is rerendered (according to bindings) I need to execute some jQuery code. What is the right place to put this code?

Comment: in a ng-change function

Comment: also, you could also use directives (preferred) for DOM changes; which is the preferred method and set up a watcher there.

Comment: out of curiosity, what jQuery code do you run?

Answer (score 0):

If the change happens say, in an input field

```
<input ng-change="runThis()" ng-model='mymodel'/>

$scope.runThis = function(){ /*do something*/ };
```

If the change can happen anywhere you can just create a watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('mymodel', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal){ // do nothing if undefined or null
        // do something
        $timeout(function(){ // dont forget to inject $timeout into controller
            // fire function after one second
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it specified that my custom watch is executed after bindings are rerendered?

Comment: the watch is executed any time the scope variable changes. so if you have $scope.myModel then you should watch like so: $scope.$watch('myModel', ...);

Comment: Yeah, but I need to exeucte jQuery code (some plugins) after bindings are updated (html is rerendered)

Comment: Well, you won't really know when it's completely re-rendered that I know of, the best you can do is do a $timeout to fire the jQuery code after some set of time.

Comment: same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304291/angularjs-how-to-run-additional-code-after-angularjs-has-rendered-a-template