# How to execute jQuery code after Angular render without create new directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I need use `jQuery UI Datepicker` in my `Angular` application, but I wan't create a new directive for this, I just want execute `$(".dateInput").datepicker();` after Angular render

How to can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to run additional code after AngularJS has rendered a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304291/angularjs-how-to-run-additional-code-after-angularjs-has-rendered-a-template)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution! using `$timeout`, fallowing my code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $("[name=data]").datepicker();
    });
}]);
```